# Javascript: How to use onResults function in mediapipe?

Tags: javascript, callback, mediapipe

I am new to javascript and I am trying to integrate mediapipe [selfi-segmentation](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/selfie_segmentation.html) in my project, the following code works fine but I do not understand whats the meaning of line

```
selfieSegmentation.onResults(onResults_sefli_segmentation);
```

to my understanding `selfieSegmentation.onResults` return `results` which we are passing to `onResults_sefli_segmentation` as parameter

But how and why are we passing a function-`onResults_sefli_segmentation` as a parameter of another function-`onResults`
Also when I am trying to integrate the code with my project its not calling `onResults_sefli_segmentation` and thus not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/camera_utils/camera_utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/control_utils/control_utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/drawing_utils/drawing_utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/selfie_segmentation/selfie_segmentation.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <video class="input_video"></video>
    <img id="background" src="/background.jpg" , style="display: none">
    <canvas class="output_canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
const videoElement = document.getElementsByClassName('input_video')[0];
const canvasElement = document.getElementsByClassName('output_canvas')[0];
const canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
var seg_background = document.getElementById("background");
function onResults_sefli_segmentation(results) {
  canvasElement.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
  canvasElement.height = videoElement.videoHeight;
  canvasCtx.save();
  canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
  canvasCtx.drawImage(results.segmentationMask, 0, 0,
    canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

  canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
  canvasCtx.drawImage(
    results.image, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

  canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
  canvasCtx.fillStyle = '#00FF00';
  canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

  canvasCtx.restore();
}

const selfieSegmentation = new SelfieSegmentation({
  locateFile: (file) => {
    return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/selfie_segmentation/${file}`;
  }
});

selfieSegmentation.setOptions({
  modelSelection: 0,
});

selfieSegmentation.onResults(onResults_sefli_segmentation);

const camera = new Camera(videoElement, {
  onFrame: async () => {
    await selfieSegmentation.send({ image: videoElement });
  },
});
camera.start();
```

Comment: do you know the concept of callbacks? If this is the question I'd recommend the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Comment: relief.melone thanks for reply, I understood that onResults_sefli_segmentation is a callback function. 
Can you also explain me which part of code is responsible for looping and passing new video frame to the the model, is it camera.start(),
also in my project I already have my video started I just want to pass the image-data to model and get prediction output. I do not want to start video again